Unity 3D entering spaceship bugged and not working
Im trying to make a game about space and spaceships, but im stuck on trying to get in to a spaceship. At first press player teleports to the same position as it was, and at second press the game becomes bugged and player doesnt teleport and spaceship flies out very fast and rotated.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EntryOpenScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isPlayerNearby = false;

    private bool isInside = false;

    private Transform player;
    public Transform getInsidePoint;

    private CharacterController characterController;

    void Update()
    {
        if (isPlayerNearby && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            if (!isInside)
            {
                EnterShip();
            }
            else
            {
                ExitShip();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")) // Upewnij się, że gracz ma tag "Player"
        {
            isPlayerNearby = true;
            player = other.transform;
            characterController = other.GetComponent<CharacterController>(); // Pobranie CharacterController
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            isPlayerNearby = false;
            player = null;
            characterController = null;
        }
    }

    private void EnterShip()
    {
        if (characterController != null)
        {
            // Wyłącz kontroler ruchu przed zmianą pozycji, aby uniknąć kolizji
            characterController.enabled = false;

            // Ustaw nową pozycję gracza
            player.position = getInsidePoint.position;

            // Włącz kontroler ruchu ponownie
            characterController.enabled = true;

            Debug.Log("Player entered the ship.");
        }
        else
        {
            // Fallback dla obiektów bez CharacterController
            player.position = getInsidePoint.position;
        }

        isInside = true;
    }

    private void ExitShip()
    {
        if (characterController != null)
        {
            characterController.enabled = false;
            player.position = transform.position;
            characterController.enabled = true;

            Debug.Log("Player exited the ship.");
        }
        else
        {
            player.position = transform.position;
        }

        isInside = false;
    }
}

It was supposed to teleport to the inside and when pressed again teleported back to the top of the ship. Also,, the mesh collider of hull of the spaceship is set to convex because other way there is no collisions when i have rigidbody attached and its needed for spaceship to fly.
EDIT:
I managed to fix it by changing the movement from rigidbody based to character controller based
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnginesPoweringSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<SingleEngineScript> engines;
    [SerializeField] private Transform thrustPoint;
    private float totalPower = 0f;

    public CharacterController thrustTarget;

    bool enginesCanBeSwitched = false;

    private void Update()
    {
       if (enginesCanBeSwitched)
       {
            // Silnik 1
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
            {
                if (!engines[0].isPowered && !engines[0].isPoweringUp)
                {
                    engines[0].StartEngine();
                }
                else if (engines[0].isPowered && !engines[0].isPoweringUp)
                {
                    engines[0].ShutEngine();
                }
            }

            // Silnik 2
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
            {
                if (!engines[1].isPowered && !engines[1].isPoweringUp)
                {
                    engines[1].StartEngine();
                }
                else if (engines[1].isPowered && !engines[1].isPoweringUp)
                {
                    engines[1].ShutEngine();
                }
            }

            // Silnik 3
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha3))
            {
                if (!engines[2].isPowered && !engines[2].isPoweringUp)
                {
                    engines[2].StartEngine();
                }
                else if (engines[2].isPowered && !engines[2].isPoweringUp)
                {
                    engines[2].ShutEngine();
                }
            }
       }

        // Aktualizacja łącznej mocy wszystkich silników
        totalPower = 0f;

        foreach (var engine in engines)
        {
            // Sprawdź, czy silnik działa i jest włączony lub się rozgrzewa
            if (engine.isPowered || engine.isPoweringUp)
            {
                totalPower += engine.GetCurrentPower();
            }
        }

        if (totalPower > 0f)
        {
            ApplyThrust(totalPower);
        }
        Debug.Log(totalPower);
    }

    private void ApplyThrust(float power)
    {
        Vector3 thrustForce = -thrustPoint.right * power;
        thrustTarget.Move(thrustForce * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
            enginesCanBeSwitched = true;
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            enginesCanBeSwitched = false;
        }
    }
}


"and spaceship flies out very fast and rotated" makes me think that you aren't disabling the player's collider once they're inside the spaceship, which causes the physics to try to eject the two objects. "Also,, the mesh collider of hull of the spaceship is set to convex" supports this, as "convex" means that the internal area of the ship is considered "inside" the collider.

thank you i finally fixed it

I'm glad you managed to fix your issue, but could you post your solution as an answer to this question, so others know that your question is solved?

i actually changed it so that its controlled by charactercontroller and not rigidbody, im gonna edit it
